# Syncfusion Essential JS 2 Diagram control

Tags: syncfusion

I'm evaluating Syncfusion Essential JS 2 Diagram control for a new app. It seems it's on "preview" state. ¿Is it usable on production?

We need to create different nodes with input/output ports and limit the connectivity depending on the port type.

I've searched the docs but I was unable to find out if that's possible right now.

¿Could someone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EJ2 diagram component is in preview state, still you can use our component. We may do only minimal changes in our diagram API or structural changes in final version.

The input/output ports and limit the connectivity depending on the port type can be achieved by using connectionChange event of Diagram. This event can be used validation on Port (whether the port is in/out port) and decide on connection changes.

Connection Change Event arguments: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/diagram/api-iConnectionChangeEventArgs.html?lang=es6

Regards,

Ramya T